Android Emulator launching successfully but won't open
I am trying to run a react native project for the first time, i have followed the exact instruction to set up my enviroment.
After running npx react-native run-android, the emulator lauches suucessfully and i get the message of Build successfull on the terminal, however my emulator wont open when i click on it.
I have tried opening it on android studio and it works perfectly.

my laptop specs:
Windows 11,
i7 12th gen,
16gb ram

kill the emulator and try to start emulator from command line with the following command :
emulator -avd 
if it doesnt work you may not have the command line tools properly setup
